# Does ColdFusion Still run scheduled tasks when apache isn't running?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, coldfusion, cron

Does ColdFusion 8 application server still run the CF scheduled tasks when apache is stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean for URLs *on* the box itself? If your CFM pages are run via Apache, then it won't do any good if CF is running.

Comment: To clarify:  Scheduled Tasks are run by making an HTTP call, so if there is no web server running, on-box tasks will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can still run them but they may not work. The ColdFusion Application Server is a separate process from the Apache Web server (httpd).

If the Apache httpd is shut down but the ColdFusion service is still running, it will attempt to run the scheduled tasks. If the task URLs themselves reference a URI space served by Apache, they will fail. If they reference a local built-in Web server (like on port 8500) or on another server entirely they will still be executed.